# Does Grails cascade deletes when not using domain.delete()?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, belongs-to, cascading-deletes

From the Grails site: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html

```
class Airport {
 String name
 static hasMany = [flights:Flight]
}
class Flight {
 String number
 static belongsTo = [airport:Airport]
}
```

Then calling `delete()` on an instance of Airport will delete any associated Flight objects (since they belongTo airport).  If I were to delete an Airport using `executeUpdate` can I still expect it to delete the Flights?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not. Here's a quick example:

```
 def a0 = new Airport(name: 'Dulles').save()
 def f0 = new Flight(number: '1000', airport: a0).save()

 assert 1 == Airport.count()
 assert 1 == Flight.count()

 Airport.executeUpdate("delete Airport a where a.name = 'Dulles'")
```

Yields (abbreviated):

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Integrity constraint violation FKB4318470B2E8D1BA table: FLIGHT in statement [delete from airport where name='Dulles']
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
        ... 27 more
```

There's an unresolved Hibernate issue requesting the ability to specify the cascade in the query [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-695).

This is also backed up on the Grails mailing list [here](http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.grails.user/msg/d95c613f0910300230w365a9e1asd2fdbab310b78d8d@mail.gmail.com).

Comment: There are probably ways you can get around this by manually configuring hibernate (hibernate.cfg.xml), if you have to.